# Increasing JVM max ram usage on unknown device

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm making a program that is capped with the amount of RAM that is allocated to the JVM (processing graphs).

So far things are running fine on my 8GB device but my ambition is to run jobs with a very large memory usage. As these actions only need doing once every graph I'm considering doing them on AWS, where currently you can get 4TB RAM devices. 
My problem is not knowing how to dynamically allocate the JVM memory limit as all option's I've seen require you to know the RAM size beforehand.

Is there a way to allocate (nearly) all RAM on a device to the JVM and if so, is there a limit?

Edit: To clarify, I'd like to have one container be usable for any device with any amount of RAM. (So the available RAM is unknown at the time of compilation)

Comment: if you remove -Xmx  your heap should increase to the system limt but: how do you prevent OutOfMemoryError if your heap limit is changing across devices??

Comment: One could use Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory once inside the jvm. But if the graph is too large it should crash in this case :) I didn't know removing -Xmx would increase it beyond a standard size, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @FranMontero When not defining the max ram usage it increases the limit to 1/4th of the system total, this is quite a waste on a 4TB machine.

Comment: Java 10 has a new option -XX:MaxRAMPercentage which you can use to specify how much percentage of RAM to use for Java heap. Is that something you can use for this purpose?

Comment: @Ashutosh That sounds exactly what I'm looking for, I can't seem to find any documentation about it though? Could you share your source?

Comment: @user12042 check it [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186315). Although these options were added to give user more control on allocation of Java heap when running in containers (like a docker container), they work should work in other environments as well.